# checkmarx scan Dereferenced Field issue

Tags: apex, checkmarx

I submitted code in checkmarx and in the result i got error as "Dereferenced Field" on following lines :

source as :

```
....
61. else return new
PageReference('/'+Vendor_Invoice_Line__c.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getKe
yPrefix()+'/e?vid='+vin.get(0).id+'&retURL=%2F'+vin.get(0).id);
```

and destination as :

```
....
70. <apex:pageBlockButtons ><apex:commandButton
value="Save" action="{!save}"
rendered="{!IF(isError==false,true,false)}"/><apex:commandButton
value="Save & New" action="{!savenew}"
rendered="{!IF(isError==false,true,false)}"/><apex:commandButton
value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/></apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

can anyone help me with this error,
i don't know why this error coming? what should i change to solve this error?

Any help would be really appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried constructing the variable before the return statement and add the return statement after?

Eg.

61.

```
else 
new String pageRefString = PageReference('/'+
    Vendor_Invoice_Line__c.sobjecttype.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()+
    '/e?vid='+vin.get(0).id+'&retURL=%2F'+vin.get(0).id);
return pageRefString;
```

We had a similar issue in our project, and this resolved the Checkmarx violation